# Притягивание полилиний друг к другу

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, polyline

подскажите, как организовать притягивание конечных вершин двух полилиний?

Например, я нарисовал первую линию и хочу продолжить рисовать с конца первой линии, вторую линию. 
Все происходит на экране мобильного устройства и не всегда можно точно попасть пальцем в область конца первой линии, чтобы рисовать вторую.

Вот бы, организовать некоторое «прилипание» друг к другу этих двух геообъектов.

Версия API карт 2.1

Comment: Задача неясна( Вы хотите нарисовать линию №2, но так, чтобы если первый клик при рисовании был в районе точки существующей линии №1, то первая точка линии №2 поставилась бы в точку линии №1? Или вы просто хотите увеличить кликабельную область линии, чтобы можно было кликнуть по точке линии и продолжить её не создавая новую линию? ( на это есть пример в песочнице https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/editor_icon_layout )

Comment: Совершенно верно, если первый клик при рисовании линии 2 был в районе конца линии 1, то точка линии 2 встала в точку конца линии 1. Продолжать линию не надо, мне нужны отдельные линии.

Comment: Как я это себе вижу. При добавлении каждой точки сохраняем координаты в отдельный массив. Дальше подписываемся на событие beforevertexadd https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geometryEditor.LineString-docpage/#event_detail__event_detail/event-beforevertexadd в нём как раз можно менять координаты перед добавлением. Дальше сравниваем координаты из нашего массива (переведённые в глобальные пиксельные с помощью map.options.get('projection').toGlobalPixels(coords, myMap.getZoom()) ) и если они отличаются не более чем на столько то пикселей, то меняем координаты при добавлении.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Попробую, отпишусь обязательно.

Comment: Спасибо! Реализовали притягивание линий и точечных объектов к вершинам линий.